# css counter-increment for section numbers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the css Counter to work. It works fine until I have a,b,c in one of the list items, then it messes up. This is what I want to display

```
1. ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS

 1.1   blah blah blah
 1.2   blah blah blah
 1.3   blah blah blah

2. Risk Statement

 2.1   blah blah blah
 2.2   blah blah blah
 2.3   blah blah blah

3. License
 3.1   blah blah blah
 3.2   blah blah blah
   a blah blah blah
   b blah blah blah
   c blah blah blah
 3.3   blah blah blah

4. License
 4.1   blah blah blah
 4.2   blah blah blah
 4.3   blah blah blah
```

What is happening is that a,b,c is being counted so 3.3 is displaying as 4.3 and then section 4 is starting at 5.1....Here it is in JSFiddle(a,b,c are not showing but ignore that - the numbering is the important thing)... http://jsfiddle.net/XQKcy/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ol li` will affect all `li` elements within the list, even those of child `ol` elements.

As such you need to identify the immediate children, and only apply to those, using `ol>li` syntax.

See the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XQKcy/14/